# Esper context usage for permission handling

Tags: esper, complex-event-processing

I want to set up viewing permissions for different users in EPL query as follows:

```
Users   AllowedView
U1      V1,V2
U2      V1,V3
U3      V2,V3

Input Events sequence are as:
  User View Amount
1. U1, V1,  20
2. U2, V3,  30
3. U3, V3,  40
4. U3, V2,  50

Output required as Sum(amount):
1. U1 - 20, U2 - 20 (as V1 is changed and permission to U1 & U2)
2. U2 - 50, U3 - 30 (as V3 is changed and permission to U2 & U3)
3. U2 - 90, U3 - 70 (as V3 is changed and permission to U2 & U3)
4. U1 - 70, U3 - 100 (as V2 is changed and permission to U1 & U3)
```

**I think context will do this, but need some help to streamline the flow of events and configuring context.**

So I need to Create context partitions on the basis of group of views.
Such as

```
Partition1 - V1,V2
Partition2 - V1,V3
Partition3 - V2,V3
```

So that all calculation can be done on the basis of them. As you can see the partitioning key of the context is not a single or double property, it is basically a group of same property. So I can not write as

```
Create context TestContext 
     partition by view 
     from EventPermissibleView;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can a single incoming event below to multiple partitions?
Perhaps a UDF is easiest that assigns a group id to each event, group id could 
be just the string-append of all views (sorted)

Comment: Would you please elaborate. I don't want to use java in between. Is there any way to define functions in esper epl? Will expression will do the trick?